# how to load the page showing a div in a particular position without moving parent elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page, let's say `1000px` wide. I have a div on that page which is `3000px` wide. On load, the div will show the first `1000px` of `3000px` until I scroll. What I want to do is show the div in position `1000px` - `2000px`, therefore, as if it has already been scrolled `1000px`, therefore it sits in its 'middle' position.

If I do this by using `left: 1000px;` then my scrollable div no longer scrolls, or, the first `1000px` of the `div` are no longer reachable. (I should mention I'm trying to do this on a mobile device, hence using the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` trick to get this div to bounce in a 'native' manner.

I'm a bit stuck with how to get this to work, if anybody can think of how to do this so that I can still scroll through my entire `3000px` div but start at position `1000px`, that would be terrific.

Comment: You should show some HTML, and in your case a JSFiddle or similar would be very useful for people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/uDy9B/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="brown"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

style:

```
div.wrap {
    width:3000px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:relative;
}
.wrap > div {
    width:1000px;
    height:200px;
}
.green { background-color:green; float:left; }
.red { background-color:red; float:left; }
.brown { background-color:brown; float:left; }

.clear {clear:both;}
```

jquery:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollLeft: '1000px' }, 1000);
```